# Django RestFramework - NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

My Model:

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey(Home, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.user.username, self.home.address)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user',)
```

My serializer

```
class WishlistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    home = serializers.RelatedField(required=True, queryset=home_models.Home.objects.all())
    user = serializers.RelatedField(required=True, queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Wishlist
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'home',)
```

My View

```
class WishlistAdd(CreateAPIView):
    """
    Add a new Home in User wishlist
    """

    serializer_class = serializers.UserWishlistSerializer
    queryset = Wishlist.objects.all()
```

When I try to do a POST request to create the new record I receive the following error: `IntegrityError at /user/wishlist/ NOT NULL constraint failed: user_wishlist.home_id`

All of these happens after a git merge, but i don't notice any differences between the branches

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your sqlite database is tracked by git. This means that whenever you switch to the broken branch, lack of data integrity causes this error – even if the application code is perfectly the same. I recommend adding the database file to your `.gitignore`, and looking into Django's fixtures instead.

Comment: The sqlite database is already in .gitignore. When the merge request is approved and the branch merged.
I've done a bash script to update the branch.
The commands i launch are:

`git pull`
`pip install -r requirements.txt`
`python manage.py migrate`
`python manage.py test`
I don't create the migrations because them are tracked

Answer (score 0):

That error means you did not provide a home id in your post payload, though this error should be caught on the serializer level because you specified required there as well. The reason it is required is because because you specified in your model field as a non-nullable field

```
home = models.ForeignKey(Home, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
```

if you dont wish for it to be required specify null=True, blank=True. Also you need to ensure that home exists. good luck.

Comment: mmh. How can i check for this into serializer?

Comment: your serializer has required true as well so i would remove that